# In a firefox extension, how to query multy selected tabs using crtl+click

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

I know how to query all tabs in the current window using things like :

```
browser.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true });
```

But I don't see how to get only selected tabs, when using the crtl+click technique

maybe something like :

browser.tabs.query({ selected: true });

But it does not exist sadly.

For context I want to do things like hiding or discarding to those tabs.

[Example in firefox to visualize the feature I am talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eST30.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this:

```
browser.tabs.query({ highlighted: true })
```

Comment: It works thanks !